# Simple mechanics problem for force diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I would like to solve this mechanics exercise. The uniform density objects R1 and R2 must fit on a rigid frame in such a way that the frame would

not topple if not fixed to the floor.  I would like to consider #1 see diagram.

(#1) in this situation I think R1 and R2 could balance by adjusting lenght of fixed supports x and y in proportion:

220/170 . x = y

so x would be 300mm and y 388mm. Is that right? Is the equivalent simple diagram correct?

[image]

Comment: Your method (balancing moments) is correct. But you need to define x and y in your diagram. Where is the pivot? The frame has an extended base.

Comment: @sammy gerbil I was thinking that the pivot would be the centre of the frame and even that the frame has an extened base it would amount to the same thing when it comes to mantaining equilibrium or balance.

Comment: If the frame has a rigid flat base, the pivots will be at both corners of the base. You must take moments about each corner separately. The result is that there will be a range of ratios  of masses R1 to R2 which will allow the apparatus to balance. If the base is very narrow (much smaller than x or y) then it will be more like having only 1 pivot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the pivot would be the right or left side of the frame depending on whether it tilts to the right or to the left.

You can base your calculation on balancing moments, but in that case you need to take into account that the objects have extension (are not points).

Is the vertical position of the objects fixed/given?

Comment: I've added some more information to make it clearer. If I say put a triangle under the centre of the frame (temporary) and adjusted the length x and y would it not eventually balance? and would the balance not be in the ratio I've calculated so that when I remove the triangle and put the frame directly on the floor it should not topple. Or am I just oversimplifying because the supports shown * cannot be ignored as I assume?